# spring @Scheduled with cron does not resolve property

Tags: spring, spring-scheduled

I'm using spring framework v4.1.7 and have issues scheduling a cron task where i want to define the cron parameter in a property file.

My java code:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${invoice.export.cron}")
private void scheduledExport() {
    // ... the code to execute ...
}
```

and in my properties file i have `invoice.export.cron: 0 0 7 * * MON-FRI?`

to enable scheduling i have `@EnableScheduling` on my main configuration class.

I tried to debug into this issue and found that the cron expression should be resolved from the property placeholder [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.1.x/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L313). following the calls into `resolveStringValue` brings me to [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.1.x/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractBeanFactory.java#L797) location into `AbstractBeanFactory`. And as far as i can see, here is the problem. the `this.embeddedValueResolvers` list is empty... therefore it does not resolve the property i passed to `@Scheduled(cron)`.

anyone has an idea if i'm doing something wrong or miss something here?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you registered a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`?

> Specialization of PlaceholderConfigurerSupport that resolves ${...}
>   placeholders within bean definition property values and @Value
>   annotations against the current Spring Environment and its set of
>   PropertySources.

I'm not sure if it works also in `@Scheduled`, but it's worth a try

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:whatever.properties")
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {

   @Bean
   public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
      return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
   }
}
```